# Facebook and OAuth 2.0

Tags: facebook-oauth

I have a C++ desktop application in Facebook. Can anyone suggest how to use OAuth 2.0 with the application? How do I specify the OAuth header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it solved. Specify the oauth header in the same way as specified in the facebook developers page. No need of oauth signature, timestamp etc..